# How to correctly parse data from Firebase Realtime Database?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database

First encounter with RealtimeDatabse - My database structure looks like this:

[image: Database Structure]

I use this code to read the data:

```
Map<String, BookingItem> bookingMap={}; // Need to populate this
final db = FirebaseDatabase(databaseURL:"https:MYURL");
                  final fb = db.reference();
                  fb.child('1b***APkCeLs/Form Responses 1').once()
                      .then((DataSnapshot data) {
                        print(jsonEncode(data.value)); // Shows up fine
                        var encod = jsonEncode(data.value);
                        try { // Problem here
                          // Need some code help with getting the data into MAP format please
                        } on Exception catch(e) {
                          print ('Error: $e');
                        }
                    debugPrint(bookingList.toString());
                  }).catchError((onError){
                    if (kDebugMode) print (onError);
                  });
```

My booking item class is simple:

```
class BookingItem {
  String email;
  //String chooseYourBookingLocation;

  BookingItem({required this.email});//, required this.chooseYourBookingLocation});

  BookingItem.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)
      : //chooseYourBookingLocation = json['Choose your booking location'],
        email = json['Email'];
}
```

I want - `Fri Jul 09 2021 07:33:09 GMT+0100 (British Summer Time)` as key and BookingItem object with sub-details as a value.

I want to just start by grabbing the email and then the rest in the next steps.
End goal is to have BookingItem Map with all the details so I can update field/fields later as well.

jsonEncode prints this on the screen

> `{"Fri Jul 09 2021 07:33:09 GMT+0100 (British Summer Time)":{"Additional Information":"","Email":"litl.com","First Name":"Laura","Choose your booking location":"Brentwood","Time":"13:00","Last Name":"Irving","Phone Number":"074","Number of Guests":5,"Timestamp":"2021-07-09T06:33:09.675Z","Date":"","Email Address":""},"Fri Jul 09 2021 10:51:06 GMT+0100 (British Summer Time)":{"Additional Information":"","Email":"sa***uk.com","First Name":"Sacha","Choose your booking location":"Brentwood","Time":"18:30","Last Name":"Leal","Phone Number":"07**4","Number of Guests":2,"Timestamp":"2021-07-09T09:51:06.939Z","Date":"","Email Address":""},"Fri Jul 09 2021 12:02:22 GMT+0100 (British Summer Time)":{"Additional Information":"","Email":"nic**om","First Name":"Nicola","Choose your booking location":"Hatfield","Time":"15:00","Last Name":"Coan","Phone Number":"07***4","Number of Guests":2,"Timestamp":"2021-07-09T11:02:22.663Z","Date":"","Email Address":""},"Fri Ju...`

I just want to simply do the following to start with:
[image]

Comment: `data.value` in your code should be a `Map<String, dynamic>` with the dates as the keys. What is the problem in the code you shared? What does `jsonEncode(data.value)` do?

Comment: it seems it is <string,dynamic> type data. I have added the output of jsonEncode above. I want exactly as you pointed out, date as key and then rest of the info to be converted to an object as value. Some code example will help a lot.

Comment: How do I get into further key:value inside the value?

Comment: Can't you see, that you made a mistake? Jul 10, 8, 15. Please, use unix timestamp instead of this

Comment: This data come from Google sheets via a script which I used. Not sure I can change that